Low voltage protection circuit
I am currently developing a esp32 PoE powered board similar to the one from Olimex (schematic, website) but I want to integreate some sensors and stuff.
I was wondering if someone has some suggestions on how to make sure that the output of this part of the circuitry is always 5V.

What I mean by that is that even if the DC-DC voltage regulator fails and somehow there are 50V on the 5V line I want to be sure to have either 5V or none at the output.
What I found so far on the internet is the following:

Use a fuse (I cannot find one rated for 5V and 1/2A)
Use a zender diode
Use a TVS diode
Use a crowbar circuit

The issue is that, while a fuse physically interrupts the flow of electricity trough it, the others go to ground, and in this case I am not sure of the consequences.
Meaning that I don't know what would happen if I basically short the Spare1 (VDD) and Ground trough one of the solutions above mentioned.
I also looked at solutions like the TPS25200 but that tolerates input up to 20V.
As a side note, connected to the 5V output there is a 3.3V 1A AMS1117 voltage regulator that can handle input voltages up to 12V.
Thank you

Can you ask a question?

Below is the LTspice sim of a circuit using a TL431 programmable reference as a comparator to cut off the output when the voltage rises above the set value:
The voltage is cut off when TL431's Ref voltage reaches 2.5V. That causes TL431 to start to conduct, which turns on Q1 and thus turns off M1 (sets it Vgs to near 0V).
Here pot U2 is set for a cutoff of 5.3V (green trace) as the input voltage (yellow trace) rises to 50V.
The PMOSFET can be any logic level type (Vgs(th) max of ≤2V) that has a least a 60V rating and a low enough on-resistance to not significantly drop voltage at the load current.

